# Exact number of elements in std::array in function call

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, stdarray

I have a function that takes an `std::array` of given size `N`

```
void func(std::array<int,3> x) {
  // do something
}

int main() {
  func({4,4,4}) // works
  func({4}) // works as well
}
```

I understand why the second call works as well, my question is: is there a way to check at compile time how many arguments I've actually passed?

The background: I don't want to second call to be allowed, I want the user to pass exactly `N` arguments.

Comment: An array have a fixed number of elements, there can never be fewer (or more) than three elements in an `std::array<int, 3>` array. Perhaps you should use `std::vector` or `std::initializer_list` instead?

Comment: Would `std::tuple<int,int,int>` be acceptable?

Comment: No, this cannot be done, due to some fundamental rules of C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Maybe not with std::array, but you can with a slightly different syntax and enable_if

Comment: What is the actual and underlying problem you try to solve? Please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: What are semantics/meaning of the values in the array? It might be a better choice to have a custom struct instead, providing clear names for any of these (like perhaps a `struct Point3D { int x; int y; int z; };` – providing an appropriate constructor accepting three arguments would enforce, too, what you intend.

Comment: `std::array` mimics c-arrays and thats how C arrays do work (except that you cannot pass c arrays by value to a function)

Comment: To be clear: both function calls pass **one** argument: an array with three elements. In the second call the array is constructed with two default values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make the function more restrictive like this :

```
#include <type_traits>
    
// let sfinae disable mismatches
template<std::size_t N>
auto func(const int (&v)[N]) -> std::enable_if_t<N==3,void>
{
  // do something
}
        
int main() 
{
    func({4,4,4}); // works
    func({4}); // no longer compiles
}
```

Demo : https://onlinegdb.com/FHlRINqCZ

Comment: In addition to the `-> std::enable_if_t<N==3,void>` it might be worth mentioning `requires (N == 3)` as well, as it's much more readable what the intent is.

Comment: @cigien I usually test on C++17 (I assume that's a version that is in widespread use) but yours is a welcome addition for C++20

Comment: I forgot to mention, that when you use templates (like this) all implicit type conversions will not be considered. And it is a property I use more often when I want a function to oonly explicitly match a type

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you might add a deleted overload:

```
void func(std::array<int, 3>) {
  // do something
}

template <std::size_t N>
requires (N != 3)
void func(const int(&)[N]) = delete;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oqzh7aEze)